Do gamma matrices commute with 4-vectors?
One of my exercises was to prove the identity
$$\gamma^\mu\displaystyle{\not}a\gamma_\mu=-2\displaystyle{\not}a.$$
Which is trivial if $\gamma^\mu a_\nu=a_\nu \gamma^\mu$, as follows
$$\gamma^\mu\displaystyle{\not}a\gamma_\mu=\gamma^\mu a_\nu \gamma^\nu\gamma_\mu = -2 a_\nu \gamma^\nu=-2\displaystyle{\not}a.$$

Does a vector of matrices commute with a vector of scalars? Well a single matrix commutes with a single scalar.

Yeah that's good reasoning, thank you.

Easy mistake to make, you're confusing "a 4-vector" with "the components of a 4-vector". Care is almost never with this language in physics because it is clear what we mean.

Each component of $a_{\nu }$ would multiply a Gamma matrix, acting as a scalar, as Connor Behan says so yes, it would commute.

Yes, they do. Something complicated about quantum field theory is that we often hide the countless tensor products that are in effect. If we use $a,b$ as spinor indices (i.e., indices labeling the spinorial entries of spinorial matrices and spinors), we can write
\begin{align}
(\gamma^\mu \displaystyle{\not}a \gamma_\mu)_{ab} &= \gamma_{ac}^\mu \displaystyle{\not}a_{cd} \gamma_{\mu,db}, \\
&= \gamma_{ac}^\mu a_{\nu} \gamma^{\nu}_{cd} \gamma_{\mu,db}.
\end{align}
This time, all terms are numbers, since we are working in components. Thus,
\begin{align}
(\gamma^\mu \displaystyle{\not}a \gamma_\mu)_{ab} &= \gamma_{ac}^\mu a_{\nu} \gamma^{\nu}_{cd} \gamma_{\mu,db}, \\
&= a_{\nu} \gamma_{ac}^\mu \gamma^{\nu}_{cd} \gamma_{\mu,db}, \\
&= a_{\nu} (\gamma^\mu \gamma^{\nu} \gamma_{\mu})_{ab},
\end{align}
at which point you can just follow your calculation and things run smoothly.
The key point is noticing that four-vector do not carry spinor indices.
